# Why android is power hungry?

Tags: battery-life

When every android phone is released, all the reviews discuss about battery life of the device, since, they say, battery life in android phones is a critical issue.

Question is :

Why battery life is an important problem in android phones ?

Some say, it is due to the display of smartphones. Some say, Android is inherently power hungry due to some of its OS related features.

Can anyone highlight the reason why Android is power hungry ?

Comment: It's not so much Android that is power hungry, but **smartphones in general** are power hungry. A smartphone basically is a very small laptop computer and as such it has a similar battery-life.

Comment: ...but what normally uses up the bulk of your battery life on a modern (large-screened) smartphone is the screen. It's usually over 50 % on my Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: `Why battery life is an important problem in android phones?` Have you seen any smartphones that can stay awake for 24 hours of constant usage without recharging? That's why.

Answer (score 3):

Just a few reasons Android uses a lot of power:

- Large, Colorful, Bright Display
- Constant Wireless Connections
- Background Applications
- Application/Cloud Syncing
- User Input
- [Garbageware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crapware) Applications running when no one asked them to
- Poorly written applications using more CPU cycles than needed

Basically, everything about your phone that makes it "smart", uses battery power - often a lot.

If you were to dim the display to minimum, turn off all wireless communications and have no applications running and syncing, your smartphone would have outstanding battery life; and be quite useless.

Comment: On my device, the Motorola Droid 3, there are pre-installed applications that I do not want, and cannot remove. They periodically run themselves and eat resources. Common names for this kind of software is: Blotware, crapware, garbageware, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crapware

Answer (score -2):

Basically Android need to be interpreted which takes more CPU cycles. Compared to very efficient systems like the Symbian and Meego Android will always use maybe 2 times more power due to most code not being native.

Comment: What is interpreted? And even if so, it does not necessarily result in increased power consumption.

Comment: Hi, you could add more details, please.